# How to fix Google Maps for ExpressionEngine - Uncaught TypeError: this.lat is not a function

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I'm getting this error all of a sudden when trying to add markers to a map in the CP:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.lat is not a function

I've previously followed all of the [advice on devot-ee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-maps#comment_box_4244) about using a previous version of the Google Maps API, but this has now happened despite doing that.

Any advice on how to work around this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following fix works for me. The project in which I'm using this fieldtype does not require the use of most of the product's more advanced features so I can't guarantee that it fixes everything. Nor can I guarantee that it won't break something else. But hey, it's a start :-)

Open up /themes/third_party/gmap/javascript/gmap_field.js and search for "var updateValues". (The line number will vary depending on your addon version.) Modify the code as follows:

```
// @HACK VMG 2016-05-26
// Fixes "this.lat is not a function" error caused by
// the response object containing float values for lat
// and lng instead of a LatLng object.
$.each(response.markers.results, function(i, result) {
    response.markers.results[i].geometry.location = new google.maps.LatLng(result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng);
        });
$.each(response.waypoints.results, function(i, result) {
    response.waypoints.results[i].geometry.location = new google.maps.LatLng(result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng);
});
$.each(response.regions.results, function(i, result) {
    response.regions.results[i].geometry.location = new google.maps.LatLng(result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng);
});
var updateValues = [
    JSON.stringify(response.markers.results),
    JSON.stringify(response.waypoints.results),
    JSON.stringify(response.regions.results)
];
```

Hopefully that helps others of you who are facing the same problem.

Comment: Life saver! This worked for me.

Comment: This worked great for me on Google Maps for EE 3.3.8. Thanks Mr Wilson! :-)

Comment: Nice one. This coupled with the fix below (it must be v3.22) worked for me.

Comment: Using the various fixes already mentioned the individual entries are working, but I still can't get the Importer to run correctly (whether it's 10 or 1000's of entries). The importer / geocoder still shows the error "this.lat is not a function"?

Answer (score 1):

You may have already tried this.
This fix worked for me a while ago (I just checked - and GMAPS is still working fine on the site this fix was applied to).

Around line 180 in this file:
system/expressionengine/thirdparty/gmap/ft.gmap.php

CHANGE THIS:

$this->EE->theme_loader->javascript('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true');

TO THIS:

$this->EE->theme_loader->javascript('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&sensor=true');

Comment: Thanks Jules, yes, this change was already in place prior to the problem appearing.

Comment: I've also noticed this same issue happening in the last day or so on all the sites I have that use Google Maps for EE. I was also using the previous patch that was listed on Devot-ee: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/google-maps/viewthread/15475

Comment: I was just going to post that I did the same fix, but when checking the site now I see that this error is back. I also get this warning in my console "Google Maps API warning: RetiredVersion https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#retired-version"

Comment: Hello, Solutions explain above are works in past. None of this is working now. Do any one have some solution ? I have gmap 3.3.9

Comment: It's best to change the line above to $this->EE->theme_loader->javascript('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true');. This ensures that you're using the latest of API V3. I think v=3.24 and below have now been retired.

Comment: I would also recommend, creating an API key in Google Developer Console and then changing the line to this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY. This also helps remove the 'sensor=true' which is no longer support because Google only lets you use the sensor on an https connection.

Comment: I can vouch for all of the above. I had implemented the v=3.22 fix from a while back on all my sites. And then I was stumped when one site was working and another was not. On the one that wasn't working I implemented the API Key fix and the v=3 and the js hack at the top of this post. And then it worked. But then I saw this last comment above mine which explained why originally one site was working and another was not. One was on https the other was not.